# Union/Merge 2 lists of different type and return a list of one type with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have an IEnumerable of type String with Default values and a fix order.
I have a List of type Module with values in a random order.
I want to have ONE list of unique objects of type Module.
What I get with the below code is:
ONE list of unique objects of type String.

Someone knows a trick around this?

```
static void Main(string[] args) {    

    List<Module> moduleList = new List<Module>() {
        new Module{ ModuleId = 1, ModuleType = "world"},
        new Module{ ModuleId = 2, ModuleType = "wayne"},
        new Module{ ModuleId = 3, ModuleType = "hallo"},
        new Module{ ModuleId = 4, ModuleType = "tes"},
        new Module{ ModuleId = 5, ModuleType = "mi"},
        new Module{ ModuleId = 6, ModuleType = "haha"},
        new Module{ ModuleId = 7, ModuleType = "pipi"},
        new Module{ ModuleId = 8, ModuleType = "bla"},  
    };

    // This result is fine that the list is unified and the predefined 
    // values order is not changed: bla, tes, mi 
    // BUT I need to return a query with Module objects

    var query = GetDefaultValues().Union(moduleList.Select(t => t.ModuleType));
}

private static IEnumerable<string> GetDefaultValues() {
    yield return "bla";
    yield return "tes";
    yield return "mi";
}
```

Do a new Module() in every lambda and copy the values is NO option for me.

**UPDATE:**

Desired output:

a list of Modules:

```
new Module{ ModuleId = 8, ModuleType = "bla"},
new Module{ ModuleId = 4, ModuleType = "tes"},
new Module{ ModuleId = 5, ModuleType = "mi"},

new Module{ ModuleId = 1, ModuleType = "world"},
new Module{ ModuleId = 2, ModuleType = "wayne"},
new Module{ ModuleId = 3, ModuleType = "hallo"},
new Module{ ModuleId = 6, ModuleType = "haha"},
new Module{ ModuleId = 7, ModuleType = "pipi"},
```

Comment: Please show the desired output in its entirety.

Comment: How do you expect to get modules when you don't create them? Maybe a Factory is an option for you? This way you can provide a list of let's say strings to the factory and get a list of modules back.

Comment: Will the result of `GetDefaultValues` always be a subset (when comparing by `ModuleType`) of `moduleList`?

Comment: I am not clear on what you are trying to do. Are you wanting to impose some ordering on the randomly ordered list of modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var query = GetDefaultValues()
            .Select(v => moduleList.Find(m => m.ModuleType == v))
            .Union(moduleList);
```

Comment: Your answer was the most easy one :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
var query = GetDefaultValues()
               .Select(t => moduleList
                               .Where(mo => mo.ModuleType == t)
                               .Single())
               .Union(moduleList);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the list of modules to be a dictionary of Modules mapped by the module type, then this code will return a query of `IEnumerable<Module>`

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

  var moduleList = new Dictionary<string, Module> {
                 {"world", new Module{ ModuleId = 1, ModuleType = "world"}},
                 {"wayne", new Module{ ModuleId = 2, ModuleType = "wayne"}}, 
                  ... 
            };

  IEnumerable<Module> query = GetDefaultValues().Select(val => moduleList[val]);
}
```

Using Dictionary will also be faster then searching in the list, if the number of modules is large enough.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but if you simply want to take the ordered strings and get the corresponding module, you can use this:

```
var modulesByType = moduleList.ToDictionary(m=>m.ModuleType);
var result = GetDefaultValues().Select(moduleType=>modulesByType[moduleType]);
```

If you want to avoid constructing the dictionary for some reason, you could also use the:

```
Func<string, Module> getModule = moduleType => moduleList.Single(m=>m.ModuleType == moduleType);
var result = GetDefaultValues().Select(getModule);
```